# Converting 12.30 PM into Seconds

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, time

I'm using http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/ to get Delivery time, so it gives

like "12.30 PM" , **business rule is the Delivery time should be greater than 4 hours of current time**, i,m using  `var currentTime = new Date().getTime()` which gives  [some long value].

now there are two questions

**how to convert  "12.30 PM into format of Date().getTime()" and how to validate the business rule.**

I'm stuck, I tried using Date.js . but not much success there.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seconds from when? 12PM? Yesterday? 1972?

Comment: Asking "how do I convert 12:30 PM into seconds" makes no sense. "Seconds" is a duration of time. "12:30 PM" is (sort of) an instant in time (but not really, because it does not specify a date, timezone, etc). Side note: [`Date.getTime()` does not return seconds.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Comment: do you agree "12.30 PM " is time, I want to know how to convert it into the format which Date().getTime() gives.

Comment: @Meistro that is my problem too, I only get 12PM and no date, but it should be considered as today's time

Comment: Create a date at "now." Then set the time component to 12:30 PM. Then you can use `Date.getTime()`. The Mozilla docs I linked provide sufficient information to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

> I only get 12PM and no date, but it should be considered as today's time

You can try combining it with a [date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) for "*today*" and [parse them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```
var timeString = '12:30 PM';

Date.parse(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + timeString)
// e.g.: 1379266200000
```

With Date.js, you should be able to just pass the time string to [`Date.parse()`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse), which has been modified from the standard method and supports parsing time strings:

```
Date.parse("12:30 PM").getTime();
// 1379266200000
```

Just note that the date and timezone will be local to the user, so the actual result may vary from one machine to another.